# How to handle empty string while sorting in descending order using python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, conditional-statements, logic

I have a list of dictionaries below

```
profile = {
          "education": [
            {
              "degree": "B.Tech",
              "start_date": "2003-01-01"
            },
            {
              "degree": "BE",
              "start_date": "2007-01-01"
            }
          ]
        }
```

I was sorting the start_date in descending order

**code:**

```
temp = []
if 'education' in profile:
    for info in (profile['education']):
      temp.append(info)
      null_values = {""}
      sorted_date = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: x["start_date"] if x["start_date"]
                                        not in null_values else "9999-99-99", reverse=True)
    print(sorted_date)
```

The above code is working if start_date exists:

Usecase1(If start_date exists):

```
profile = {
              "education": [
                {
                  "degree": "B.Tech",
                  "start_date": "2003-01-01"
                },
                {
                  "degree": "BE",
                  "start_date": "2007-01-01"
                }
              ]
            }
```

**O/p:-**

```
[{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}, {'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': '2003-01-01'}]
```

Use case2(If start_date value is empty):

```
profile = {
          "education_details": [
            {
              "degree": "B.Tech",
              "start_date": ""
            },
            {
              "degree": "BE",
              "start_date": "2007-01-01"
            }
          ],
        }
```

**O/P:-**

```
[{'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': ''}, {'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}]
```

**Note:** If the start_date value is empty, place this item at the end.

**Expected O/P:-**

```
[{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'},{'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': ''}]
```

Use case(check if start_date exists or not):

```
profile = {
          "education_details": [
            {
              "degree": "B.Tech",
              # "start_date": ""
            },
            {
              "degree": "BE",
              "start_date": "2007-01-01"
            }
          ],
        }
```

**O/P:-**

KeyError: 'start_date'

**Expected o/p:-**

```
[{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}, {'degree': 'B.Tech'}]
```

Please help me, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get` method of dictionaries for eluding of exceptions. And I do not recommend to sort every time per iteration in loop. This can be done in the end.

```
temp = []
if 'education' in profile:
    for info in (profile['education']):
        temp.append(info)
    null_values = {""}
    sorted_date = sorted(temp,
                         key=lambda x: x.get("start_date", "0000-00-00"),
                         reverse=True)
    print(sorted_date)
```

The result for the empty string:

`[{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}, {'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': ''}]`

Comment: Hi Vovin, thanks for the answer, Use case2 (Expected o/p) is missing

Comment: @XDSauaame What do you mean under "missing"? I got `[{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}, {'degree': 'B.Tech'}]` as the result of my proposed code.

Comment: As per the use case2: if start_date is empty (start_date = ""), we need to display like [{'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}, {'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': ''}] but getting [{'degree': 'B.Tech', 'start_date': ''}, {'degree': 'BE', 'start_date': '2007-01-01'}]--(if start_date is empty then add that date item in the end) I hope this was clear now

Comment: @XDSauaame This is caused by your value after `else`: `"9999-99-99"`. I will edit my answer now.